# Removing html5 required attribute with jQuery

Tags: jquery, attributes

Hi I would like to remove the 'required=""' attribute with jquery.

```
<input 
   type="text" 
   id="edit-submitted-first-name" 
   name="submitted[first_name]" 
   value="" 
   size="30" 
   maxlength="128" 
   required=""
>
```

Answer (score 154):

Just:

```
$('#edit-submitted-first-name').removeAttr('required');​​​​​
```

If you're interested in further reading take a look [here](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/).

Answer (score 65):

If you want to set required to `true`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#edit-submitted-first-name').prop('required',true);
});
```

if you want to set required to `false`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#edit-submitted-first-name').prop('required',false);
});
```

Comment: The best possible way to do this. I have tried other solution but this one helps me a lot. thx

Comment: Thanks. I was trying the "removeProp('required')" function but that didn't do anything. This worked great.

Answer (score 34):

### Using Javascript:

```
document.querySelector('#edit-submitted-first-name').required = false;
```

- [More Info Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation#The_required_attribute)

---

### Using jQuery:

```
$('#edit-submitted-first-name').removeAttr('required');
```

- [More Info Here](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)

Comment: jQuery handles such checks for you so you don't have to explicitly check the attribute exists before attempting to remove it.

Answer (score 15):

```js
$('#id').removeAttr('required');​​​​​
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Even though the ID selector is the simplest, you can also use the name selector as below:

```
$('[name='submitted[first_name]']').removeAttr('required');
```

For more see: https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/