# Bypass HTML "required" attribute when submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, form-submit, requiredfieldvalidator

I use `required` for a 1st check before submitting a form.

```
<form action="myform.php">
  Foo: <input type="text" name="someField" required="required">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
  <input type="submit" value="ignore">
</form>
```

Problem is, that I have an "ignore" button, which submits the form as well and the backend logic then sets a correct state in a DB. In this case (ignore) the validation is not desired (because there is no need to fill in field "Foo").

What's the best way to handle the 2 scenarios?

1. I am aware that I could give up "required" and do the validation somewhere else (backend / JavaScript). I am looking for a way to keep the "required".
2. I could use some Js `onclick` for the ignore button scenario and remove the attribute just before sending the form ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/13951500/356726 ).

But actually I am looking for something smarter ....

--- Edit ---

Yes, duplicate of [Required attribute HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004703/required-attribute-html5)

Comment: #2 would probably be the best bet. That or do the validation server-side completely rather than with the required attribute, bypassing the validation if the ignore submit was used rather than the submit submit.

Comment: #2 makes sense to me too.

Comment: Yes, I have missed the above

Comment: In the second case just `$('form').clone().find(':required').prop('required', false).closest('form').submit();` and the original `form` will stay untouched. Never tried one line coded, it's just to give you the idea.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

No JavaScript, no second form needed, and the validation can stay:

For exactly this use case the HTML5 spec has designed the [`formnovalidate` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fs-formnovalidate) for submit elements (like [`<input type=submit>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#submit-button-state-%28type=submit%29)), as one of the [attributes for form submission](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attributes-for-form-submission):

> The `formnovalidate` attribute can be used to make submit buttons that do not trigger the constraint validation.

So simply put

```
<form action="myform.php">
  Foo: <input type="text" name="someField" required>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
  <input type="submit" value="ignore" formnovalidate>
</form>
```

Answer (score 5):

Your #2 is a common approach. Something like:

```
$('input[value="ignore"]').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('input[type="text"]').removeAttr('required');
});
```

Might have to use mousedown to beat submit.

Comment: If JavaScript was to be used, you should better do `.prop("required", false)`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use Javascript, you could make them separate forms and have all the inputs set to hidden for the `ignore` form.

Not the best option, but it is an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You should use approach #1 on the following grounds: The main reasons for using `required` instead of JavaScript validation is that it is simpler and it works even when JavaScript is disabled. Here the simplicity does not apply, since the use of `required` makes things more difficult. And the latter reason does not apply either: with JavaScript disabled and the browser supporting `required`, the “ignore” button does not work unless some data is entered in the textfield.

Another alternative is the one mentioned on @MattKenefick’s answer. It might even result in simpler structure and logic. If the form is really as simple as in the example, it is straightforward to split it to two forms:

```
<form action="myform.php">
  Foo: <input type="text" name="someField" required="required">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<form action="myform.php">
  <input type="submit" value="ignore">
</form>
```

Comment: It does not mean "*the field is required in all circumstances*". It does mean "the field is required when the form is validated" - which it might not, see my answer.

Comment: @Bergi, right, I’ve removed that paragraph.