# html5 custom attributes required message not working

Tags: html

Hello i have an osclass website, i made some custom fields required with this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("#countryId").attr('required', 'required');
        $("#regionId").attr('required', 'required');
        $("#city").attr('required', 'required');
        $("#cityArea").attr('required', 'required');
        $("#contactName").attr('required', 'required');
        $("#price").attr('required', 'required');
</script>
```

please help me to change the default message to : "please fill out this field"

Thank you very much

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25628209/dynamically-change-required-for-html5-input-control

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set custom HTML5 required field validation message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13798313/set-custom-html5-required-field-validation-message)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will be helpful
 `<input type="text" required title="Custom message" />`

Comment: just add the title attribute to the input element

Comment: well you can use it through jQuery like this

Comment: $('#countryId'). attr("title", "Custom message");

Comment: can you show all of your code and please do not type it in comments instead edit the question and type code

Comment: hello, 'm sorry but i'm new here. I have deleted my comments and i included the link with full code in my question. Thanks