# Remove Required attribute after select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this search bar:

[image]

I dont want user to make a full search because there are like 40000 records on database and it will take a while.

So I split that in 2 options and I have the first field as required,

`<select required name="field1" id="destination" tabindex="-1" class="select2-hidden-accessible" aria-hidden="true">
  <option name="country" value="">Field</option>
  <option name="country" value="%">Any destination</option>
</select>`

But I need to remove that required field if they choose Field 2 or Field 3.

So I think best practice is to do something like `onchange` and remove that required with something like this `.removeAttribute("required")`?

Whats the easiest way to do that? Vanilla or JQuery? I am a beginner on JavaScript so any feedback would be helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery removing html5 required attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13951336/jquery-removing-html5-required-attribute)

Comment: @Maria, can you accept the best suitable answer you found among all?

Comment: I have to wait like 49 secs still :D

Comment: @Maria, :D You are right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do like this using jquery: **(Assuming that field2 and field3 are id of those dropdown fields.)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var field2 = '';
    var field3 = '';
    $('#field2').on('change',function(){
        field = $(this).val();
        removeRequired();
    });
    $('#field3').on('change',function(){
        field3 = $(this).val();
        removeRequired();
    });
    function removeRequired(){
      if(field2 != '' && field3 != '')
      {
          $('#destination').removeAttr('required');
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeap that worked, just had to to change && to || cause I just wanted one of these fields... Cheers

Answer (score 5):

You can simply add this one

```
$("field1").prop('required',false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo code to do this:

```
if(field2.value || field3.value) {
     $("field1").removeAttr("required");
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can either use jquery [removeAttr](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_removeattr.asp) function or use javascript [removeAttribute](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_removeattribute.asp) function