# remove required attr with if condition from database use json in laravel 5.6

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-5.6

I want to make condition if database have data js will give attr required but if database not have a single data, attr required wil removed

this for my json

```
$(document).ready(function () {

// ================== CHANGE ====================

$("#no_reg").change(function(e) {
console.log(e);
var no_reg_id = e.target.value;
$.get("/PickStandart/" + no_reg_id, function(data) {
  console.log(data);

  $('#standart').empty();
  $('#standart').append('<option value="">-- Select One --</option>');
  $.each(data, function (index, row) {
      if (row.name != null) {
        $('#standart').attr('required', 'required');
      }
      else {
        $('#standart').removeAttr("required");
      }

      $('#standart').append('<option value="'+ row.id +'">' + row.name + '</option>')
    });

});
});

});
```

my problem is, I cant remove required attr if data is null

this for my json code

```
$bagian = Bagian::where('id', '=', $standart)->first();

if ($bagian->standart_klausul == 1) {
  $standart = Standart::where('aktif', '=', 1)->get();
  return response()->json($standart);
}
```

Comment: Did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19166685/jquery-add-required-to-input-fields) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13951336/jquery-removing-html5-required-attribute)?

Comment: yeah, Im not wrong in .attr or .removeAttr but I get error if database send data and if that data is null, I want to remove required but not removed @ImeshaSudasingha

Comment: In javascript we will get `undefined` if `data.name` is not available. So, use `if(data.name)` in the condition. If condition will evaluate `data.name` and consider as false if `data.name` is `null or undefined`

Comment: can you fix my code and I will try it @ImeshaSudasingha

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

// ================== CHANGE ====================

$("#no_reg").change(function(e) {
console.log(e);
var no_reg_id = e.target.value;
$.get("/PickStandart/" + no_reg_id, function(data) {
  console.log(data);

  $('#standart').empty();
  $('#standart').append('<option value="">-- Select One --</option>');
  $.each(data, function (index, row) {
      if (row.name) {
        $('#standart').attr('required', 'required');
      }
      else {
        $('#standart').removeAttr("required");
      }

      $('#standart').append('<option value="'+ row.id +'">' + row.name + '</option>')
    });

});
});

});
```

Note the `if` condition. I have used `row.name` instead. As I mentioned in a comment,

In javascript we will get `undefined` if `data.name` is not available. So, use `if(data.name)` in the condition. If condition will evaluate `data.name` and consider as false if data.name is `null or undefined`

Comment: its not working for me, remove required is not working

Comment: How does your `row` json look like?

Comment: No, can you add the json response you are getting? put a `console.log(row)` and comment the output.

Comment: this data I get `[{"id":1,"name":"OS 1","klausul":1,"aktif":1},{"id":2,"name":"OS 2","klausul":0,"aktif":1},{"id":3,"name":"OS 3","klausul":1,"aktif":1},{"id":4,"name":"OS 4","klausul":1,"aktif":1},{"id":5,"name":"OS 5","klausul":0,"aktif":1}]`

Comment: According to your data, all rows have a valid `name`. So, your `else` won't be called anytime. If this is not what you want to do, you have a problem in your logic.

Comment: thats my problem and how I fix that, but if data is nol, `console.log(row)` dont have any value

Comment: Then add 
   `if (row) {
        $('#standart').attr('required', 'required');
      }
      else {
        $('#standart').removeAttr("required");
      }`
in before the `$.each()`. It will do.