# Removing 'required' attribute with user action Thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, jquery, thymeleaf

Currently creating a Spring application with Thymeleaf as the front-end component.

When a user selects a checkbox within a form, I want to immediately remove the `required` attribute from any subsequent tags in that form. This way, the user can submit the form immediately, rather than being forced to enter data for the `required` input fields.

[image: Checkbox]

This^ checkbox is checked. It should allow the user to save immediately, instead of this:

[image]

I believe that JQuery is needed for what I am trying to do. I found this possible solution:

[Removing html5 required attribute with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13951336/removing-html5-required-attribute-with-jquery)

but I have no experience with JQuery, and this solution only indicates how to *remove* a required field, rather than when an action happens. Is there a simpler way to handle this task?

My form markup for reference:

```
<!-- When the user clicks "save", this data routed here -->
        <form action="#" th:action="@{/ots/resolve/save}"
            th:object="${griefRecord}" method="POST">

            <div class="checkbox">
                <label data-toggle="popover" data-content="Checking this box will Exclude this record">
                <input type="checkbox" name="exclude"/>Exclude this Record?</label>
            </div>

            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-default"
                    data-toggle="popover" data-content="Adjust the Platform">Platform</span>
                </div>
                <input type="text" th:field="*{platform}"
                    class="form-control" placeholder="platform" required>
            </div>

            <button type="submit" id="index-popover"
                class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" data-toggle="popover"
                data-content="Save the listed record to the Cross Reference Table">Save</button>

        </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set an `id`, eg. `reqfield` on the inputs with `required` attribute, then you can use the following code:

```
$(function(){

    $("input[name=exclude]").change(function(){
     if(this.checked){
        $("input#reqfield").removeAttr("required")
     } else {
        $("input#reqfield").attr("required", true)
     }
    })

})
```

Comment: Unfortunately after testing, this did not work. I checked the console but received no notifications. Users are still required to enter values despite having clicked the "excludes" checkbox :(